# Selecting incorrect submenu item after hover action

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm developing a test case in Python with Webdriver to click through menu items on http://www.ym.com, and this particular one is meant to go through a menu item and click on a sub-menu item.

When running the test, it looks like it tries to access the nested menu items, but never clicks on the final item. Here is my code to go through the menu:

```python
food = driver.find_element_by_id("menu-item-1654")
hov = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(food).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li/a")).click()
hov.perform()
```

The problem here is that I am trying to click the "Recipes" submenu from the "Food" menu, but what happens is the submenu "France" is being clicked under the menu "Travel" which is situated right next to "Recipes.

I've tried using find_element_by_id, find_element_by_css_locator, find_element_by_link_text but it seems to always select the France submenu under Travel and not the Recipes submenu under Food.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I am using this Python code to run the test now:

```
food = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'category/food/')]/..")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(food).perform()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'category/recipes-2/')]/..")).click()
```

which works perfectly fine in IE, but still access the wrong menu item in Firefox.

Comment: Correct, it will go to hover over Food, go down to then hover/click on Recipe, but when it scrolls over it pulls up the Travel>France tab and clicks on that instead. I will try your method in the morning and see if that works for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use normal click instead of ActionChains' move and click.

Changes to your code:

1. I assume the ids are dynamic, try avoid using them.
2. Try avoid using absolute xpath
3. Use normal click rather than ActionChain move and click
4. Use 5 seconds WebDriverWait for recipes link.

```python
food = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'category/food/')]/..")
hov = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(food).move_by_offset(5, 45).perform()
# 45 is the Height of the 'FOOD' link plus 5

recipes = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'category/recipes-2/')]/.."))
recipes.click()
```

A tested working C# version of the code:

```c#
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.yumandyummer.com");
IWebElement food = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href, 'category/food/')]/.."));
new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(food).MoveByOffset(5, food.Size.Height + 5).Perform();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
IWebElement recipes = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href, 'category/recipes-2/')]/..")));
recipes.Click();
```

Comment: Hm, even with the normal click it's still accessing the "France" submenu under the "Travel" menu.

Comment: @KMcK: I have just run the c# version of the above code , works fine. I will try run the python version if I have time. Could you also please debug yourself, to see `recipes` element is found correctly (e.g text, location, displayed, enabled etc.)?

Comment: @KMcK: e.g. From C# version, `recipes` has the following properties: Displayed = true, Enabled = true, Location = {X = 470 Y = 327},   Selected = false, Size = {Width = 180 Height = 33}, TagName = "li", Text = "RECIPES"

Comment: @KMcK: Also if you try hover and click the `Travel` - `France`, does it work?

Comment: It works under the IE profile, but still access the Travel>France in FireFox. Very strange, and can't figure out why it does that.

Comment: @KMcK: What's the Firefox version are you using? Firefox's native actions are always weirder than IE and Chrome.

Comment: @KMcK: And your Selenium version is?

Comment: @KMcK: Run my C# version against Firefox 20 just now, I can reproduce your issue, I'll investigate more.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it! I'll append the original question to include my exact Python code.

Comment: @KMcK: Workaround found (see updated answer above, using move_by_offset, you need to test this workaround for all three browsers). The root cause is still unclear, as the `Recipes`'s width is the combined width of `FOOD`, `TRAVEL` and `ABOUT`, and appears due to css changes rather than DOM changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your XPath is off? Could you try this for the XPath instead:

`find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='menu-more-menu-items']//li[2]//ul/li[1]/a[1]")`

Comment: Unfortunately that XPath also leads to the same incorrect submenu item. It's the craziest thing, I can't figure it out.

Comment: Quite strange. The only things I can think of are that the France link is actually right under the Recipes link so maybe the click is bleeding through? What if you mouse over the food link then wait for visible on the recipes link then click on it?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not that helpful, but in java I have used

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("MyId"))).selectByVisibleText("MyText");
```